# How to fill MacOS menubar with background color for timer?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, timer

I found a very interesting timer app for MacOS that fills the menubar with a background color, so you can easily see how much time is left for the timer.

Here is an image of the effect in the menubar:

[image]

When the timer is running, the background color fills the menubar from left to right.

How can I create that effect using Swift in Xcode?

Comment: You will probably need to make it translucent and animate the background

Comment: @LeoDabus – Thanks for your comment. The problem is that the translucent view will cover the menubar menu items. What are your thoughts?